# Get the remaining while exact

Tags: java

I have a list of **Exp Collector Pot** and those store some experience for a player (MMORPG game)

`private static final List<ExperienceCollectorPot> COLLECTORS = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();`

The maximum exp a **Exp Collector Pot** can use is: **10.000**

Each time a player is killing a monster and take an amount of experience, the number of the **Exp Collector Pot** he has on him are draining the experience and store it on them.

What I'm trying to do it's the following:

Let's say the player receive an amount of 5.000 experience and he has 3 **Exp Collector Pot**. The experience should be divined by **3** so each pot should store **1666** experience.

If a **Exp Collector Pot** reaches the maximum exp it can carry which is **10.000** then it self destroy but it don't drain the whole exp. If the **Pot** has let's say **9.999** experience stored then it will use only **1** of the **1666** that it deserve. Then the other POT will absorb more experience.

The problem is that i cannot think of the MATH to do this.
The class for the **Pot** is a simple record:

`public static record ExperienceCollectorPot(int getId, long getExp) {}`

So far I made the division of the total experience which is this:

`final int maxExpPerCollector = Math.max(1, EXPERIENCE / COLLECTORS.size());`

but then I simply don't know what I need to do to make the system work like I mentioned. I understand programming but I'm terrible at math and logical operations.

Comment: Please be more restrained in your use of bold - it makes it really hard to read the post. There's no need to emphasize every number in the post, or every use of "Exp Collector Pot".

Comment: I'm sorry i tried to make it easier for viewers to understand.

Comment: @Girlsarebeautiful: I can see that you have made a good effort to make your question clear and well formatted. Good job! But Jon is right, there is no need to make numbers bold. And it's still a little hard understand, but I will try. :)

Comment: I'm really sorry people, i'll undo it.

Comment: No problem, it is a really nice first question, there is no way to know things like this when you start out. :)

Comment: Alright i just though that ill help viewers to understand. Anyways as i said i'm good in programming (decent) but i suck at logical operations and Math. That is why i really need someone to point me out what to do.

Comment: Look up the modulo operator (%). That's probably the simplest way to go.

Answer (score 1):

This problem turned out to be surprisingly tricky! Because the XP to distribute between the pots changes for each pot that reaches its maximum...

I think you have to do something like the following to calculate the experience for each pot. There might be a simpler solution, but it doesn't come to mind.

```
public class XpTrying {
    public static int maxXp = 10_000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int xpToAssign = 8_000;

        var potXpList = new ArrayList<Integer>(List.of(7_000, 4_000, 9_000));

        var assignedXpList = calcXpAssignment(xpToAssign, potXpList, maxXp);

        System.out.println(assignedXpList); // Prints [3000, 4000, 1000]
    }

    /**
     * @param xpToAssign The total amount of XP to assign
     * @param potXpList  The list of current XP, each element is for one pot.
     * @return A list of XP to assign to each pot, the indices corresponds to those
     *         in the input list.
     */
    private static List<Integer> calcXpAssignment(int xpToAssign, List<Integer> potXpList, int maxXp) {
        // The XP that each pot is assigned, or null if not yet assigned
        var assignedXpList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(potXpList.size(), null));

        // The number of pots that have not yet been assigned an XP amount
        int nrPotsLeft = potXpList.size();

        // The amount of XP that has not yet been assigned to a pot
        int xpLeftToAssign = xpToAssign;

        // Is set to true if a pot is maxed out during the current traversal of the pots
        boolean isAnyMaxedOut;

        // Calculate XP assignment for all pots that are maxed to. That is, they reach
        // the maximum allotment of XP.
        do {
            int assignmentXp = xpLeftToAssign / nrPotsLeft;

            isAnyMaxedOut = false;
            int potIx = 0;

            for (int storedPotXp : potXpList) {
                if (storedPotXp + assignmentXp > maxXp && assignedXpList.get(potIx) == null) {
                    int potXpToAssign = maxXp - storedPotXp;
                    xpLeftToAssign -= potXpToAssign;
                    assignedXpList.set(potIx, potXpToAssign);

                    nrPotsLeft--;
                    isAnyMaxedOut = true;
                    break;
                }

                potIx++;
            }

        } while (isAnyMaxedOut);

        // Assign XP to all pots that weren't maxed out
        int assignmentXp = xpLeftToAssign / nrPotsLeft;
        int potIx = 0;

        for (Integer potXp : assignedXpList) {
            if (potXp == null) {
                assignedXpList.set(potIx, assignmentXp);
            }
            potIx++;
        }
        return assignedXpList;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm glad im not the only one who found this too difficult to think. i felt completely useless with this logical problem. But it must be a better solution using Math library or so maybe?

Comment: @Girlsarebeautiful: I don't thing Math library would help. Maybe the solution can be simplified a little, but not much I'm think. It really is a bit tricky!

Answer (score 0):

I'll write the answer assuming I only work with integers, if the max number is 10.000 I see no reason not to work on 10000 instead, but should be pretty straightforward to transform it to doubles.

There is probably a simpler/cleaner way to write this, but it should give you a starting point at least

As pointed out by the comments, this assumes the pot list is sorted by fill amount - pot 0 is always as filled or more than pot 1 etc. And if it's not for some reason - you could copy it into a list that is sorted and run this code.

```
int amountPerPot = exp / COLLECTORS.size();
int expRemaining = exp;
while(it.hasNext()){
  ExperienceCollectorPot pot = it.next();
  if (pot.getRemainingSpace() > amountPerPot) {
    pot.add(amountPerPot);
    expRemaining = expRemaining - amountPerPot;
  } else {
    int amount = amountPerPot - pot.getRemainingSpace();
    pot.fill(); //technically we add in "amount", but we just calculated that's exactly how much can fit anyway
    expRemaining = expRemaining - amount;
    it.remove();
    amountPerPot = expRemaining / COLLECTORS.size();
  }
}
```

So basically, iterate over pots, attempt to add the amount you want per pot, and on failure fill te pot, destroy it, remove from the list and recalculate the amount you want to fill in per pot going forward. This assumes there always is enough pots to fill in all the exp, otherwise you need to handle that too somewhere here (or you'll get a divide by 0 in the last line). Also, assumes that broken pot gets removed from the list (which happens via `it.remove()` call), otherwise you'd need to separately track the amount of pots to process for the recalculation.

Comment: I think maybe you miss the fact that if a pot is filled, that increases the XP for each other pot. That can cause other pots to get filled also, that has already been visited in the loop! Because of this, I don't think a single loop is enough. Funny little problem!

Comment: Do your solution work for this input? Stored pot XP: 7000, 4000, 9000. XP to assign: 8000

Comment: @Lii That's what the recalculation in the `else` does. We put in the amount that fits than recalculate the amount we'll try to put for all the remaining pots. I am assuming that pots are ordered by the fill amount (that is, pots are filled starting from pot 0, and it's not possible that pot 0 is not filled by exp gain that fills pot1)

Comment: I'm still trying to find a solution, i even tried my own but i failed. None of the above answers helped me.

Comment: @Girlsarebeautiful If both of those answers failed to help you're going to have to add some information as to what specifically is the problem. Maybe by editing the question to put in the code you tried and how does it fail.

Comment: @Deltharis: Sorting the pots by EXP in advance is a good idea! That makes this solution simpler and better than mine I think.